# Postman Как перебрать параметр в URL?

Tags: postman

У меня есть мини-сайт. Пытаюсь отработать функцию перебора параметра в URL. Не понимаю как сделать.

Условно: Пусть есть сайт site.local. Он обрабатывает параметр id. Т.е. запрос выглядит как `GET http://site.local?id=1`

Пытаюсь выполнить n-зарпросов c `id = 0..n-1`. где с каждого должен быть получен результат. Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте во вкладке `pre-request script`  написать код:

```
let ids = pm.collectionVariables.get("ids");

if(!ids || ids.length == 0) {
    ids = [...Array(N).keys()];  // N - нужно число
}

let currentId = ids.shift();
console.log(currentId);
pm.collectionVariables.set("id", currentId);
pm.collectionVariables.set("ids", ids);
```

во вкладке Tests

```
const ids = pm.collectionVariables.get("ids");

if (ids && ids.length > 0){
    postman.setNextRequest("Loop Query Parameter");
} else {
    postman.setNextRequest(null);
}

pm.test("Status code is 200", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status(200);
});
```

А в окне запроса написать

```
http://site.local?id={{id}}
```